# How I see data from main page by serially

Tags: php

I have a mysql table "catagory". column like that
`catagory_id,catagory_name` and some values.I want to see id serially and product from main page 
Example:

```
**Product Catagory**
Hardware
Software
Others
```

Comment: ok so a SELECT query? what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
$get_categories_sql = mysql_query("SELECT catagory_id,catagory_name FROM catagory ORDER BY catagory_id ASC");
while($get_categories = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_categories_sql))
{ 
echo $get_categories['catagory_id']."<br>";
}
```

First, Use `SELECT` query to get data from database then to display it serially(one after another), just add `<br>`,

Comment: please don't suggest people use the depreciated mysql_ api